Changing resolution and coord.ref in bathymetric maps
I want to model the movement of fish. Therefore I get a bathymetric map from gebco and masked the land masses.
library(terra)
tif_file <- "~/path_to/GEBCO_map.tif"
map <- rast(tif_file)
map <- ifel(map >= 0, NA, abs(map))

until here I have everything under control. Now I want to change the resolution of the map to a coarser scale and I need to change the coordinates reference.
print(res(map))
[1] 0.004166667 0.004166667 
# I want to change that to 100x100

coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# I want to change that to coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 29N (EPSG:32629) 
# for that I have a reference map (mapE) 
map_reprojected <- project(map, crs(mapE))

# Trying to get the desired resolution (e.g., 100 x 100 meters)

new_resolution <- c(100, 100)
current_resolution <- res(map)

# Calculate the target number of rows and columns based on the desired resolution

target_ncols <- ncol(map) * (current_resolution[1] / new_resolution[1])
target_nrows <- nrow(map) * (current_resolution[2] / new_resolution[2])

# Create a dummy raster with the new resolution but same number of rows and columns

dummy_raster <- rast(ext(map), nrows = round(target_nrows), ncols = round(target_ncols), resolution = new_resolution)

# Resample the original map to the new resolution while keeping the number of rows and columns

map_resampled <- resample(map_reprojected, res = new_resolution, method = "bilinear")

My problem is, that once I adjust the resolution, my dimensions of the map go to 1,1,1 and I have NAs everywhere. Is there any way to change just the resolution of the map?
Changing the coord.reference works but is the map still correct then ? When I plot it, it looks worbed.

The way to resample a raster to another resolution is to provide the target raster to resample() function. Don't have your GEBCO data, therefore an general example:
r <- terra::rast(nrows = 1800, ncols = 3600, vals = sample(1:10, 1800*3600, replace = TRUE))
terra::plot(r)


Now, let's say that the the target raster has to have coarser resolution, therefore we are creating a raster with different rows/columns numbers and the same extend:
s <- terra::rast(nrows = 50, ncols = 50)
u <- terra::resample(r, s)

terra::plot(u)


You can create the target raster a bit differently, by copying the source raster and setting the resolution with res() function as you did, however please note the help which is saying: When setting dimensions, all cell values are dropped. Therefore we have to resample() it from r to s:
s <- r
terra::res(s) <- c(10, 10)
s
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 18, 36, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84)

u <- terra::resample(r, s)
terra::plot(u)


Now you can transform the CRS using project() function:
terra::project(u, "ESRI:102016") |>
  terra::plot()


Created on 2024-12-27 with reprex v2.1.1.9000

I think it is not a good idea to first resample and then project as that will distort the data twice.

Thanks for your advice, but in my case the dimension and not the resolution gets altered, what am I doing wrong?
`> print(map)
#class       : SpatRaster
#dimensions  : 4080, 4369, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.004166667, 0.004166667  (x, y)
#extent      : -86.19583, -67.99167, 21.00833, 38.00833  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)
#min value   :                                               1
#max value   :                                            6238
s <- rast(nrows = 100, ncols = 100)
map_resampled <- resample(map, s)
`

print(map_resampled) #class       : SpatRaster  #dimensions  : 100, 100, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr) #resolution  : 3.6, 1.8  (x, y) #extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) #coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)  #min value   :                                        49.81379  #max value   :                                      5497.16260

what you are after may be as simple as
library(terra)
map_reprojected <- project(map, mapE)

but if the extent or resolution of mapE are not what you want you can do something like this
x <- rast(mapE)
res(x) <- 100000
map_reprojected <- project(map, x)


Thanks for your advice! I tried it and it introduces NAs into my map, so in the end I can’t plot it. What am I doing wrong? The extents of the 2 maps are not the same because it's different regions.
`> x <- rast(mapE)

res(x) <- 100
map_reprojected <- project(map, x)
print(map_reprojected)
class       : SpatRaster
dimensions  : 264, 190, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent      : 695492.1, 714492.1, 6246657, 6273057  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 29N (EPSG:32629)
min value   :   NaN
max value   :   NaN`


please edit your question and included this information.
